# Two input signals at the same always block

Tags: verilog

I am working with an DE2-70 board and I am trying to use some of it's buttons as inputs. The buttons are activated at 0, and I need to check if two buttons in particular are being pressend separatly, in order to increase/decrease a number.

I tried doing the following, where iKEY are the buttons and position is the number i am trying to modify:

```
reg [4:0] position;
position = 5'b0;

output wire enable = !(iKEY[3] && iKEY[2]);
always @(posedge enable) begin  
    if(iKEY[3] == 0)
        position = position + 5'b00001;

    if(iKEY[2] == 0)
        position = position - 5'b00001;
end
```

I tried several differences of this implementation, such as tring to change the ifs conditions or changing the logic function when setting the enable signal, but I always get stuck in some problem. 
I am new to hardware logic, so maybe I am thinking in it in the wrong way

Edit:
If both buttons are pressed at the same time I expect the hardware to neither increment nor decrement the number

Comment: What do you expect to happen if 2 or more buttons are pressed at the same time?

Comment: If possible, I'd like it to do nothing. I will edit my question stating this

Comment: Other then a missing `initial` before `position = 5'b0;`, I don't see anything that stands out as working. It is not clear what problem you are running into. Please share a link to your full code and join me in chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39387/questions-19415793

Comment: You might need to de-bounce your buttons as well.   You'd be best served by solving this problem with a state machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Summary of the chat discussion:*

- **Missing key background** information:

  - `iKEY` is 4-bit active low input. Input source is from physical buttons,
  - A operation should happen on a one-cold (inverse of one-hot) `iKEY`,
  - There are clocks available, such as the 50MHz `iCLK_50`
- **Solution** for operations executing unexpectedly:

  - Move all the all the `iKEY` into one always block and decode the operation with a case statement. Ex:

    ```
    case(iKEY[3:0]) // one-cold, full-case
      4'b1110: /* operation 0 */
      4'b1101: /* operation 1 */
      4'b1011: /* operation 2 */
      4'b0111: /* operation 3 */
      default: /* default behavior */
    endcase
    ```
  - If using `iKEY` as a clocking event, then perform a bit-wise NAND operation:

    ```
    wire enable = ~&iKEY[3:0];
    ```
  - If using using the `iCLK_50` clock, then add a reg to watch for button release to insure one operation per button press. Ex:

    ```
    if (allow_op) begin // value from past clock event
      /* case statement defined above */
    end
    // value for next clock event
    allow_op = &iKEY[4:0]; // bit-wise AND
    ```

Answer (score 0):

You probably should be looking for a CHANGE in the button press.  The code below looks for a falling edge on the iKEY[3] input.  Otherwise, as soon as IKEY is pushed, that counter will go NUTS and start incrementing or decrementing like crazy.

```
reg iKEY3_LAST;

output wire enable = !(iKEY[3] && iKEY[2]);
always @(posedge enable) begin  
  iKEY3_LAST = iKEY[3];
  if(iKEY[3] == 0 && iKEY3_LAST == 1)
    position = position + 5'b00001;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you have a combinational loop on signal position. When enable=1 position will change and then change again and again. Simulations will usually get stuck in this case, as for the real world, it depends on how your tools implemented it; I guess most of them will just break the loop. Look for any errors or warnings in the logs.
You want position to be a flop, so it will not be a loop, but will increment by 1 every clock cycle:

```
always @(posedge clock or posedge reset)
if (reset)
   position <= 5'h0;
else
   position <= position + iKEY[3] - iKey[2];
```

Now you must take into account that buttons introduce the bouncing effect. Look [here](http://www.labbookpages.co.uk/electronics/debounce.html) for more information. You'll probably want to implement the Digital Switch Debouncing.

And as Russell wrote, you might consider changing the position only on falling edge of the buttons, otherwise the counter will overflow/underflow like crazy.